# Given n points where each point has its own range, adjust all points to maximize the minimum distance of adjacent points

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, mathematical-optimization

Take n points in one dimension:

[image]

Each point can be moved within a certain range indicated by the arrow above it. These ranges are known. Ranges can overlap. How can these points be adjusted so that minimum distance of adjacent points is maximized?

I would be okay with an approximation as well.

Edit:
I am not really looking for code but a general strategy.
I have really no idea how to solve this.

Originally, I thought a greedy algorithm might work.

1. Let p0 be the starting point and pn the ending point. Let dist(p0,p1) represent the distance between p0 and p1.Well obviously adjust p0 as far left as possible and pn as far right as possible.
2. Next, find dist(p0,pn)/n-1. This represents the optimal distance each point should be from each other to be as spread out as possible. Move p1 as close to this distance.
3. Find dist(p1, pn)/n-2. Move p2 as close to this distance as possible.
4. Repeat for rest of points.

This doesn't work because adjusting another pointer later on might ruin the previous points.

Comment: This isn't a coding service.  What have you tried and what isn't working?  Suggest you edit your post to show your work and highlight what element you are having trouble with.  I would be okay with pseudocode as well.  :)

Comment: I edited the post. I am not looking for code, just a general strategy.

Comment: Can you assume the ranges don't overlap or overlap only very minimally (as shown in the picture)?

Comment: How efficient does this need to be? I.e., how many points can there be?

Comment: No. It is very likely in my scenario that many points will overlap completely.

Comment: @Dave, that is a difficult question to answer. The problem I am trying to solve is actually much larger in scope than this one. I have a system that sends out multiple periodic messages. When scheduling these messages, I can schedule them with some jitter(range) of their periods. In this example, points represent my messages, the range represents some jitter the message may use. Since this system sends out messages for an arbitrary length of time, their are presumably an arbitrary number of points.

Comment: This problem can be formulated as a MIP. Of course, meta-heuristics are another approach.

Comment: MIP as in Mixed Integer Programming?

Comment: Yes, Mixed-Integer Programming. It is non-convex so we need binary variables (or something similar) to calculate the absolute values.

Comment: This is out my depth unfortunately. This algorithm needs to be used in an MCU so I don't know how much leeway I am going to get. When I was looking up meta-heuristics, I read about stochastic optimization. That got me thinking about randomly generating an offset for each point. If the the random values have a uniform distribution, can I expect my points to take on an uniform distribution as well maybe leading to a more maximal minimum distance?

Comment: For the number of points, could you view this as a moving horizon problem? If you have `N` points in the queue, perform an optimization problem to get a good result for the first `m`. As you're sending those more points roll in and you repeat. It seems like in the situation you describe it's unlikely you'll have the full dataset available at any one time.

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing. For the points I do have available, find the optimization. Then when a new set of points show up, perform a different optimization on those. Continue ad infinitum.

Comment: I tried a few formulations here: http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2021/06/arranging-points-on-line.html. The linear MIP model seems to perform quite well. I understand this method may not be applicable for you due to hardware restrictions. It may still be useful to compare with other approaches as the MIP model delivers proven optimal solutions.

Comment: Great write up. However, you are right that it won't be very applicable to my situation. I have a similar question for minimizing the sum of squared distances between these points that I will be posting about soon as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some Ruby code, followed by sample results. The idea is to start with a random allocation of points to values within their ranges. Then we repeatedly do the following:

```
1. Find the minimum gap
2. Find all points that border a minimum gap
3. Re-randomize the values of those points
```

All the while, we remember the best solution so far. This won't give you the best possible result, but should give you a reasonably good result.

For the sample run, I gave a 'good' set of points by allocating 100 points evenly in a range of about 1100, then gave each point a range around that val. The algorithm was just given the ranges in random order. It's possible to get an input set of points where the best possible min gap is small or zero, which no algorithm can help with.

```
def test(n, range, max_attempts)
  points = get_points_with_optimal_min_gap(n, range)
  puts "input: #{points}"
  allocation = allocate_points(points, max_attempts)
  puts "solution: #{allocation.keys.sort}"
  puts "best gap: #{get_min_gap(allocation, points)}" 
  puts "\n\nallocation:"
  allocation.keys.sort.each do |k|
    puts "  #{k} => #{allocation[k]}"
  end
end

def get_points_with_optimal_min_gap(n, range)
  points = []
  1.upto(n) do |num|
    points.append([[0, num * range/n - rand(5*range/n)].max, num * range/n + rand(5*range/n)])
  end
  return points.shuffle
end




def allocate_points(input_points, max_attempts)
  val_to_points = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = []}
  input_points.each do |point|
    val = get_rand_val_for_point(point)
    val_to_points[val].append(point)
  end
  
  
  best_min_gap = -1
  best_allocation = nil
  attempts = 0
  while attempts < max_attempts do
    attempts += 1
    min_gap = get_min_gap(val_to_points, input_points)
    if min_gap > best_min_gap
      best_min_gap = min_gap
      best_allocation = deep_copy(val_to_points)
      puts "found new gap after #{attempts} tries: #{best_min_gap}"
      attempts = 0
    end
    vals_to_adjust = get_vals_bordering_min_gap(val_to_points, min_gap)
    points_to_reallocate = []
    vals_to_adjust.each do |val|
      points_to_reallocate += val_to_points.delete(val)
    end
  

    
    points_to_reallocate.each do |point|
      new_val = get_rand_val_for_point(point)
      val_to_points[new_val].append(point)
    end
  end
  return best_allocation
end


def get_vals_bordering_min_gap(val_to_points, min_gap)
  vals_bordering_min_gap = Set.new()
  if min_gap == 0
    val_to_points.each do |val, points|
      vals_bordering_min_gap.add(val) if points.size > 1
    end
  else
    sorted_vals = val_to_points.keys.sort
    
    prior_val = sorted_vals[0]
  
    1.upto(sorted_vals.size - 1) do |i|
      cur_val = sorted_vals[i]
      cur_gap = cur_val - prior_val
      if cur_gap == min_gap
        vals_bordering_min_gap.add(cur_val)
        vals_bordering_min_gap.add(prior_val)
      end
      prior_val = cur_val
    end
  end
  return vals_bordering_min_gap.to_a
end


def get_min_gap(val_to_points, input_points)
  return 0 if val_to_points.size < input_points.size
  
  sorted_vals = val_to_points.keys.sort
  prior_val = sorted_vals[0]
  
  min_gap = nil
  1.upto(sorted_vals.size - 1) do |i|
    cur_val = sorted_vals[i]
    min_gap = cur_val - prior_val if min_gap.nil? || cur_val - prior_val < min_gap
    prior_val = cur_val
    return min_gap if min_gap == 1
  end
  return min_gap
end


def get_rand_val_for_point(point)
  return point[0] + rand(point[1] - point[0] + 1)
end

def deep_copy(int_to_arr_of_int_pairs)
  new_hash = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = []}
  int_to_arr_of_int_pairs.each do |int, arr|
    arr.each do |int_pair|
      new_hash[int].append([int_pair[0], int_pair[1]])
    end
  end
  return new_hash
end
```

Sample Results

```
input: [[207, 258], [754, 826], [957, 993], [127, 158], [332, 352], [539, 615], [213, 236], [572, 590], [668, 712], [802, 823], [385, 427], [595, 641], [924, 1018], [20, 50], [698, 749], [318, 335], [64, 120], [462, 521], [708, 760], [513, 569], [806, 877], [364, 380], [732, 799], [896, 923], [947, 997], [250, 281], [798, 857], [717, 795], [542, 583], [910, 964], [277, 315], [168, 221], [263, 337], [858, 920], [316, 348], [646, 705], [557, 573], [293, 315], [48, 131], [488, 522], [252, 271], [269, 326], [43, 106], [673, 728], [399, 432], [140, 184], [564, 630], [906, 973], [508, 566], [0, 17], [493, 547], [782, 817], [184, 246], [230, 305], [5, 90], [446, 507], [429, 449], [822, 917], [35, 127], [630, 699], [888, 944], [899, 917], [179, 201], [715, 785], [40, 65], [338, 415], [908, 958], [2, 31], [469, 517], [649, 718], [96, 150], [380, 428], [347, 401], [197, 289], [849, 912], [603, 642], [805, 830], [564, 629], [19, 88], [80, 151], [593, 660], [932, 994], [479, 541], [291, 331], [175, 192], [842, 877], [987, 1028], [382, 432], [796, 884], [102, 160], [535, 587], [621, 696], [461, 476], [131, 170], [437, 469], [343, 410], [660, 713], [122, 171], [699, 752], [776, 782]]
found new gap after 1 tries: 0
found new gap after 2 tries: 1
found new gap after 8 tries: 2
found new gap after 9 tries: 3
found new gap after 35 tries: 4
found new gap after 87 tries: 5
found new gap after 384 tries: 6
found new gap after 8043 tries: 7
solution: [4, 12, 20, 31, 43, 51, 59, 68, 82, 102, 110, 119, 127, 134, 141, 148, 161, 172, 179, 188, 202, 209, 223, 233, 244, 251, 258, 273, 284, 299, 308, 326, 335, 344, 351, 361, 369, 376, 383, 395, 408, 415, 423, 430, 438, 454, 468, 482, 491, 499, 508, 515, 524, 532, 539, 549, 557, 574, 582, 589, 596, 615, 623, 634, 642, 649, 656, 663, 676, 693, 720, 728, 741, 748, 758, 769, 776, 786, 801, 808, 815, 827, 834, 842, 851, 858, 865, 872, 882, 899, 911, 935, 943, 952, 962, 974, 987, 996, 1011, 1028]
best gap: 7


allocation:
  4 => [[0, 17]]
  12 => [[5, 90]]
  20 => [[2, 31]]
  31 => [[20, 50]]
  43 => [[19, 88]]
  51 => [[40, 65]]
  59 => [[35, 127]]
  68 => [[43, 106]]
  82 => [[64, 120]]
  102 => [[96, 150]]
  110 => [[80, 151]]
  119 => [[48, 131]]
  127 => [[122, 171]]
  134 => [[102, 160]]
  141 => [[140, 184]]
  148 => [[127, 158]]
  161 => [[131, 170]]
  172 => [[168, 221]]
  179 => [[179, 201]]
  188 => [[175, 192]]
  202 => [[184, 246]]
  209 => [[207, 258]]
  223 => [[197, 289]]
  233 => [[213, 236]]
  244 => [[230, 305]]
  251 => [[250, 281]]
  258 => [[252, 271]]
  273 => [[263, 337]]
  284 => [[269, 326]]
  299 => [[277, 315]]
  308 => [[293, 315]]
  326 => [[291, 331]]
  335 => [[318, 335]]
  344 => [[316, 348]]
  351 => [[332, 352]]
  361 => [[347, 401]]
  369 => [[343, 410]]
  376 => [[364, 380]]
  383 => [[338, 415]]
  395 => [[382, 432]]
  408 => [[399, 432]]
  415 => [[380, 428]]
  423 => [[385, 427]]
  430 => [[429, 449]]
  438 => [[437, 469]]
  454 => [[446, 507]]
  468 => [[461, 476]]
  482 => [[479, 541]]
  491 => [[469, 517]]
  499 => [[462, 521]]
  508 => [[488, 522]]
  515 => [[493, 547]]
  524 => [[513, 569]]
  532 => [[508, 566]]
  539 => [[535, 587]]
  549 => [[539, 615]]
  557 => [[557, 573]]
  574 => [[542, 583]]
  582 => [[572, 590]]
  589 => [[564, 629]]
  596 => [[564, 630]]
  615 => [[595, 641]]
  623 => [[603, 642]]
  634 => [[630, 699]]
  642 => [[593, 660]]
  649 => [[621, 696]]
  656 => [[649, 718]]
  663 => [[646, 705]]
  676 => [[660, 713]]
  693 => [[668, 712]]
  720 => [[673, 728]]
  728 => [[699, 752]]
  741 => [[698, 749]]
  748 => [[717, 795]]
  758 => [[708, 760]]
  769 => [[715, 785]]
  776 => [[776, 782]]
  786 => [[732, 799]]
  801 => [[754, 826]]
  808 => [[802, 823]]
  815 => [[782, 817]]
  827 => [[805, 830]]
  834 => [[806, 877]]
  842 => [[796, 884]]
  851 => [[798, 857]]
  858 => [[822, 917]]
  865 => [[842, 877]]
  872 => [[858, 920]]
  882 => [[849, 912]]
  899 => [[899, 917]]
  911 => [[896, 923]]
  935 => [[906, 973]]
  943 => [[888, 944]]
  952 => [[908, 958]]
  962 => [[910, 964]]
  974 => [[957, 993]]
  987 => [[932, 994]]
  996 => [[947, 997]]
  1011 => [[924, 1018]]
  1028 => [[987, 1028]]
```

---- UPDATE ----

I added code to try to find the optimal gap for a given ordering. This is significantly better.

allocate_points() changed, and I added a new method called attempt_to_achieve_min_gap().

```
def attempt_to_achieve_min_gap(val_to_points, target_min_gap)
  new_val_to_points = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = []}
  
  leftmost_val = val_to_points.keys.min
  leftmost_point = val_to_points[leftmost_val][0]
  new_val_to_points[leftmost_point[0]].append(leftmost_point)
  
  sorted_vals = val_to_points.keys.sort
  prior_val = leftmost_val
  1.upto(sorted_vals.length - 1) do |i|
    cur_val = sorted_vals[i]
    cur_point = val_to_points[cur_val][0]
    target_val = prior_val + target_min_gap
    if target_val <= cur_point[0]
      new_val_to_points[cur_point[0]].append(cur_point)
      prior_val = cur_point[0]
    elsif target_val <= cur_point[1]
      new_val_to_points[target_val].append(cur_point)
      prior_val = target_val
    else
      return false
    end
  end
  return new_val_to_points
end


def allocate_points(input_points, max_attempts)
  val_to_points = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = []}
  input_points.each do |point|
    val = get_rand_val_for_point(point)
    val_to_points[val].append(point)
  end
  
  
  best_min_gap = -1
  best_allocation = nil
  attempts = 0
  while attempts < max_attempts do
    attempts += 1
    min_gap = get_min_gap(val_to_points, input_points)
    if min_gap > 0
      found_improvement = true
      while found_improvement
        found_improvement = false
        trial_min_gap = [min_gap, best_min_gap].max + 1
        improved_results = attempt_to_achieve_min_gap(val_to_points, trial_min_gap)
        if improved_results
          found_improvement = true
          min_gap = trial_min_gap
          puts "found improvement!: #{min_gap}"
          val_to_points = improved_results
        end
      end
    end
    if min_gap > best_min_gap
      best_min_gap = min_gap
      best_allocation = deep_copy(val_to_points)
      puts "found new gap after #{attempts} tries: #{best_min_gap}"
      attempts = 0
    end
    vals_to_adjust = get_vals_bordering_min_gap(val_to_points, min_gap)
    points_to_reallocate = []
    vals_to_adjust.each do |val|
      points_to_reallocate += val_to_points.delete(val)
    end
  

    
    points_to_reallocate.each do |point|
      new_val = get_rand_val_for_point(point)
      val_to_points[new_val].append(point)
    end
  end
  return best_allocation
end
```

New sample results:

```
input: [[0, 21], [787, 819], [614, 642], [503, 553], [771, 854], [701, 740], [768, 807], [475, 480], [223, 251], [431, 473], [19, 67], [711, 764], [650, 673], [381, 401], [832, 907], [303, 357], [414, 480], [201, 215], [130, 182], [233, 269], [335, 417], [637, 704], [193, 242], [566, 632], [854, 927], [545, 577], [548, 574], [552, 607], [812, 868], [949, 962], [290, 334], [299, 372], [0, 31], [234, 304], [488, 540], [132, 215], [975, 994], [389, 406], [378, 437], [685, 721], [410, 453], [750, 800], [856, 919], [237, 270], [322, 355], [964, 1018], [67, 90], [925, 1015], [736, 792], [755, 823], [29, 78], [709, 761], [828, 897], [873, 927], [464, 533], [332, 380], [788, 831], [354, 413], [500, 545], [144, 196], [96, 138], [925, 982], [0, 67], [183, 207], [83, 116], [665, 679], [843, 904], [654, 694], [892, 955], [179, 203], [56, 87], [575, 636], [484, 542], [380, 439], [592, 689], [419, 431], [654, 700], [907, 978], [136, 151], [242, 313], [96, 126], [975, 1023], [449, 491], [866, 924], [117, 177], [291, 351], [460, 485], [959, 1004], [797, 846], [210, 277], [207, 240], [138, 184], [536, 606], [710, 774], [695, 714], [71, 83], [617, 629], [284, 302], [576, 633], [88, 137]]
found new gap after 1 tries: 0
found improvement!: 2
found improvement!: 3
found improvement!: 4
found improvement!: 5
found improvement!: 6
found new gap after 1 tries: 6
found improvement!: 7
found new gap after 5 tries: 7
found improvement!: 8
found improvement!: 9
found new gap after 2 tries: 9
found improvement!: 10
found new gap after 5686 tries: 10
solution: [0, 12, 22, 32, 42, 56, 67, 77, 87, 97, 107, 117, 127, 137, 147, 157, 167, 177, 187, 197, 207, 217, 227, 237, 247, 257, 267, 277, 287, 297, 307, 317, 327, 337, 347, 357, 367, 377, 389, 399, 409, 419, 429, 439, 449, 459, 469, 479, 489, 499, 509, 519, 529, 539, 549, 559, 569, 579, 589, 599, 614, 624, 634, 644, 654, 664, 674, 684, 694, 704, 714, 724, 734, 744, 754, 764, 774, 784, 794, 804, 814, 824, 834, 844, 854, 864, 874, 884, 894, 904, 914, 925, 935, 949, 959, 975, 985, 995, 1005, 1015]
best gap: 10


allocation:
  0 => [[0, 31]]
  12 => [[0, 21]]
  22 => [[0, 67]]
  32 => [[19, 67]]
  42 => [[29, 78]]
  56 => [[56, 87]]
  67 => [[67, 90]]
  77 => [[71, 83]]
  87 => [[83, 116]]
  97 => [[88, 137]]
  107 => [[96, 126]]
  117 => [[117, 177]]
  127 => [[96, 138]]
  137 => [[132, 215]]
  147 => [[136, 151]]
  157 => [[144, 196]]
  167 => [[130, 182]]
  177 => [[138, 184]]
  187 => [[179, 203]]
  197 => [[183, 207]]
  207 => [[201, 215]]
  217 => [[207, 240]]
  227 => [[223, 251]]
  237 => [[193, 242]]
  247 => [[237, 270]]
  257 => [[210, 277]]
  267 => [[233, 269]]
  277 => [[234, 304]]
  287 => [[242, 313]]
  297 => [[284, 302]]
  307 => [[291, 351]]
  317 => [[290, 334]]
  327 => [[303, 357]]
  337 => [[322, 355]]
  347 => [[299, 372]]
  357 => [[354, 413]]
  367 => [[335, 417]]
  377 => [[332, 380]]
  389 => [[389, 406]]
  399 => [[381, 401]]
  409 => [[378, 437]]
  419 => [[419, 431]]
  429 => [[380, 439]]
  439 => [[410, 453]]
  449 => [[431, 473]]
  459 => [[414, 480]]
  469 => [[460, 485]]
  479 => [[475, 480]]
  489 => [[449, 491]]
  499 => [[464, 533]]
  509 => [[488, 540]]
  519 => [[484, 542]]
  529 => [[500, 545]]
  539 => [[503, 553]]
  549 => [[545, 577]]
  559 => [[548, 574]]
  569 => [[566, 632]]
  579 => [[552, 607]]
  589 => [[536, 606]]
  599 => [[576, 633]]
  614 => [[614, 642]]
  624 => [[617, 629]]
  634 => [[575, 636]]
  644 => [[592, 689]]
  654 => [[650, 673]]
  664 => [[637, 704]]
  674 => [[665, 679]]
  684 => [[654, 694]]
  694 => [[654, 700]]
  704 => [[695, 714]]
  714 => [[685, 721]]
  724 => [[709, 761]]
  734 => [[701, 740]]
  744 => [[711, 764]]
  754 => [[750, 800]]
  764 => [[710, 774]]
  774 => [[768, 807]]
  784 => [[736, 792]]
  794 => [[787, 819]]
  804 => [[755, 823]]
  814 => [[788, 831]]
  824 => [[771, 854]]
  834 => [[797, 846]]
  844 => [[812, 868]]
  854 => [[828, 897]]
  864 => [[832, 907]]
  874 => [[843, 904]]
  884 => [[866, 924]]
  894 => [[873, 927]]
  904 => [[856, 919]]
  914 => [[854, 927]]
  925 => [[925, 982]]
  935 => [[892, 955]]
  949 => [[949, 962]]
  959 => [[907, 978]]
  975 => [[975, 994]]
  985 => [[964, 1018]]
  995 => [[959, 1004]]
  1005 => [[925, 1015]]
  1015 => [[975, 1023]]
```

Comment: If ranges overlap, choose the next point to be the one that satisfies the gap constraint and leaves you least constrained otherwise. I can detail this if it's an issue.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I am not 100% convinced this will always deliver the optimal solution. It is greedy in a sense (tries to make the leftmost points smaller first).

Comment: This is a nice solution, but I think there are scenarios where it fails. As @Erwin points out, you may get a better solution starting from the right than from the left. Also, if the ranges of the points overlap, as OP confirms they can, then there is a combinatorial number of points which could be left- or right-most.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this algorithm? I don't understand what it is doing. I understand that we are iterating from left-to-right. What does "no solution" mean? How is g defined? Is it redefined each iteration? If we've already moved the points, why is a binary search involved?

Comment: @Appren: Fix an upper and lower bound for `g` both of which are unrealistically large and small: 0 and 9999 are probably sufficient. Note that in a special case (see my previous comment) you can verify if a particular `g` works in linear time. Now do a binary search on possible values of `g` for an _O(N log UpperG)_ algorithm.

Comment: @Richard Agreed. This needs work since the point ranges have overlap; not sure if it's salvageable but will leave it up while I'm noodling on it.

Comment: @Richard We could combine this with randomization akin to simulated annealing. Assign points randomly within their ranges, then proceed with this.  Possibly we do some sub-iterations where we only re-randomize points which realize the min gap. Getting expensive though.

Comment: @Apprentice_Programmer I updated my answer and gave some code. There's room for optimization & it's randomized so won't give the best possible solution in most cases.

Comment: @Apprentice_Programmer This could also be combined with the approach I gave earlier; use this to get random orderings, then use those as starting points for binary search on the optimal gap.

Comment: This could be further improved. In the late stages we have a pretty good ordering, and using attempt_to_achieve_min_gap() gets the optimal min gap for any ordering. At this point, we could search the k points ending with our first failure to increment the gap to see if there's a point among those k that would work, and whether it can be repositioned while retaining the desired min gap.

Answer (score -1):

You can binary search on the gap size: Perform your existing steps 1 and 2 to get an upper bound `gap` on the best achievable gap size. Set `delta = gap / 2`. Now continue laying out other points exactly `gap` apart until this either completes successfully or causes an impossible situation: If it completes, set `gap += delta`, otherwise set `gap -= delta`. Either way, set `delta /= 2` and rerun. Repeat until `delta` drops below your desired precision threshold.

Comment: There's no canonical ordering of the points, and overlapping ranges are common.

Comment: @Dave: It's sufficient to only consider solutions having points in order of their increasing leftmost range endpoint (LRE), so this can be used to order them. (Suppose an optimal solution positions p2 to the left of p1, even though p1's LRE begins to the left of p2's: Then p1 and p2 can be swapped to produce a new optimal solution in which LRE order is respected for these two points. This can be repeated for all adjacent pairs of wrongly ordered points to produce a new optimal solution having points in order of increasing LRE.) With this order fixed, overlapping ranges don't matter.

Comment: @j: There's no guarantee that it's just adjacent pairs.

Comment: @Richard: If there are any pairs that are out of order, there is an adjacent pair that is out of order, so repeatedly fixing up adjacent pairs eventually fixes up the entire order. (This is why bubble sort works.)

Comment: Say the points are [0,100], [1,1]. The optimal solution has points at 1 & 100, which is not ascending LRE. The best you can do in ascending LRE is 0,1.

Comment: @Dave: You're right, I hadn't considered nested ranges. Thanks!